# regex to match optional group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to write a regex to match three groups, and I out of three groups I want one group to be optional.

**Regex:**

```
^[A-Z]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}:\s(\w*)\((\w*)\)*:\s(.*)$
```

**It matches the following:**

```
AAAA-1235: fix(test): message
```

However, not below.

```
AAAA-1235: fix: message
```

How to modify regex so that it matches both the group. And in case first message get's three groups.

- Fix
- test
- Message

And in case of second message only two groups

- Fix
- Message

Message

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

You're not making the group optional, you just made the `)` at the end of the group optional. You need to put `()` around the whole group, not just the part inside the parentheses.

Also, to make something optional, use `?`. `*` means to allow any number of repetitions, including 0.

```
^[A-Z]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}:\s(\w*)(\(\w*\))?:\s(.*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vb3aLg/1)